# XSLT html output problem with

Tags: .net, html, xslt, xhtml

The problem is, that my XSLT-Transformation process ( called by .NET ), doesn't leave the HTML content in the XSLT file alone ( which isn't xml-compliant like an `<img>` tag without an closing slash-sign ), so i'll get errors like:

```
<pre>System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: XSLT-Compilererror. ---> System.Xml.XmlException:
The 'img'-Starttag in Line XY does'nt match with the Endtag of 'td'.</pre>
```

How can I prevent this?

I would like the XSLT-processor either to ignore all the content which is no "" element or just get it to recognize the valid html-tags..

My XSL-Header looks like this ( copied from C#, so imagine the additional " are not there ):

```
"<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" " +
"xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" " +
"exclude-result-prefixes=\"html\">" +
"<xsl:output method=\"xhtml\" omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\" indent=\"yes\"/>" +
"<xsl:preserve-space elements=\"*\" />"
```

Comment: For info - it is much easier to keep your xslt in either files or resx; writing xslt inside C# strings is just painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way around this. XSLT *is* an implementation of XML and the content of an XSLT document must respect XML standards to compile.

Fix your HTML to XHTML formatting.

Comment: Well, i don't unterstand this... the <img>-tag without closing slash IS XHTML1.0 compliant but messes with xml-node architecture in the same time... i mean, everbody using XSLT to generate HTML would have this problem...

Comment: No, an unclosed img element is never valid in xhtml; it must be either <img.../> or <img...>...</img>

Comment: An unclosed *anything* is invalid - it's just that empty elements have two ways to implement closure.

Comment: That was sensible answer .. so +1

Answer (score 1):

You either have to make the HTML inside the XSLT XML-compliant (which is still valid HTML), or if you really have to have the HTML be not XML-compliant, encapsulate the html in a CDATA block.

For instance:

```
<xsl:template .... >
    <![CDATA[
        <img src='...' >
    ]]>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this is very ugly, and you would probably be better off making your HTML XML-compliant.

Comment: CDATA won't render the tag out though, it'll be rendered as "&lt;img src='...'&gt;"

Comment: Good point. I now remember doing something very dodgy with output-escaping to get around that, but I clearly blocked that out.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to output? html or xhtml? You always write the xslt as valid xml:

```
<img src="somepath" ... />
```

or

```
<img src="somepath{withvalues}" ... />
```

But you use the `xsl:output` to control it; if you want html (i.e. ) then you would use:

```
<xsl:output method="html" ... />
```

(note no "x" in the above) - or:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" ... />
```

AFAIK, "xhtml" is not a valid option for [`xsl:output/@method`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp), since it is already covered by "xml". You should also note the subtle default behaviour if you *don't* specify an `xsl:output/@method` depends on the top element (i.e. whether it starts `<html>...</html>` or not).

Comment: fwiw, xhtml output is produced by output="xml" with appropriate doctype-system and doctype-public attributes to fix the type

Answer (score 0):

XHTML is as the name X implies XML img tags or any other none closed tags is not XHTML-strict compliant. However to easy transition from HTML to XHTML several levels of "strict"-ness is available, some of them not being XML compliant.

if you rewrite your HTML to XHTML-strict you will have no problem